# Solve reports it can't handle my equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation

```
Solve[x ϵ + (-ϵ) x^-ϵ - c (-ϵ) x^(-ϵ - 1) == 0, x]
```

Yields

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

What can I do to solve this equation?

Comment: For numeric `ϵ` you could use `FindRoot`.

Comment: you should define all the symbols except `x`. thit is the simplyfiyed equation `c + x^(2 + \[Epsilon]) == x`

Comment: Since you are trying to solve a polynom, whose degree depends on an arbitrary constant, there should also be an arbitrary number of roots, i.e.: There might not be an "easy" closed solution at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short:** There is no closed solution, but you can get solutions for specific values of `ϵ`.

**Detailed explanation:**

First, we can transform your equation into a more compact form by using `FullSimplify` (and replacing `ϵ` with `e` for less typing within *Mathematica*):

```
eq = (x ϵ + (-ϵ) x^-ϵ - c (-ϵ) x^(-ϵ - 1) /. ϵ -> e //FullSimplify) == 0
(* e x^(-1 - e) (c - x + x^(2 + e)) == 0 *)
```

Now we continue by evaluating both factor components separately: First the easy one (`e x^(-1 - e) == 0`) using `Reduce`, giving us the conditions for `x` and `e`, under which this part becomes 0:

```
Reduce[e x^(-1 - e) == 0, x]
(* (x != 0 && e == 0) || (Re[e] < -1 && x == 0) *)
```

Then to the second part `c - x + x^(2 + e) == 0`: This one already looks odd, since it comprises a polynom of degree varying with `e`, but why not try our luck with `Reduce` again? So:

```
Reduce[c - x + x^(2 + e) == 0, x]
(* Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >> *)
```

Ah - bad luck! But why is that?

As a polyom's number of roots, which we are looking after by trying to solve for `==0`, depends on the polynom's degree, there will be no closed solution, as the degree depends on `e` here.

How can this be proofed with *Mathematica*? E.g. by solving for some given values for `e` and counting the number of solutions for each specific value of `e` (i.e. the number of roots for each `e`):

```
Length /@ Table[Solve[c - x + x^(2 + e) == 0, x], {e, 1, 20}]
(* {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22} *)
```

As anticipated, the number of roots equals the polynom's degree, which is `2+e`. **Therefore, there will be no closed solution** - even with `e` limited to the domain of positive integers.

**In essence**, your equation requires solving arbitrary-degree polynomials.

You therefore will need to solve for specific values for `e` to get results, e.g. by using the Table-method I outlined above.

Even then, starting from `e==3`, this involves solving a quintic (and higher) polynom(s), so *Mathematica* will give you solutions based on the generic `Root` builtin, meaning you will only be able to get numeric results for specific `c` and `e`.

Comment: "In short" hits the point and "Detailed explanation" s exactly that +1!

Comment: You rock! Great explanation!

Comment: @zsljulius: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I recommend Manipulate to investigate the function. Note as x, c and ϵ are used. With the information found You can start better studies

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x ϵ + c x^(-1 - ϵ) ϵ - x^-ϵ ϵ
 , {x, -6., 6.}]
 , {c, -6., 6.}
 , {ϵ, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First (for a given Epsilon):

```
eq = x ϵ + (-ϵ) x^-ϵ - c (-ϵ) x^(-ϵ - 1) == 0
```

then:

```
FullSimplify @ eq
```

Thus it suffices to solve:

```
c - x + x^(2 + ϵ) == 0
```

Then

```
sol = Solve[(c - x + x^(2 + ϵ)) == 0, x]
```

delivers the solutions. If you want the solutions for e.g.,c = 5, then

```
c = 5; x /. sol
```

will show them.

When Epsilon is is not given, Solve is not able to find the solutions.

Comment: Hmm. With my *Mathematica* 10.0.2 here, your `Solve`-line still leads to the same error message: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." Would you mind putting the actual solutions you got into the answer?

Comment: Ditto for V9.0.1.  I don't understand how this answer has received three upvotes (to date).

Comment: Ditto for V8.0.4.  V7 gives a slightly different error, "Solve::tdep:  The equations appear to involve the variables to be solved for in an essentially non-algebraic way."  What version are you using?

Comment: I did not add the result of FullSimplify@eq (but it is quite obvious). It is ` x^(-1 - \[Epsilon]) (c - x + x^(2 + \[Epsilon])) \[Epsilon] == 0`. So one solution is (\[Epsilon]>0) x=0, the others one gets solving `c - x + x^(2 + \[Epsilon])==0`, which gives the result(s).

Comment: @mgamer: But `c-x+x^(2+\[Epsilon])==0` is exactly the part, which is _not_ solvable with all *Mathematica*-versions tested so far (see comments above)! If you managed to get a solution, please post it in your answer. Otherwise, please revise your answer.

Comment: @ Jinxed: You are right, I can not reproduce my yesterday-result. There I got a lot of root-objects as solution, and I can not see what got wrong (I always start with a clean notebook). Sorry. Solve can only get results with given Epsilon, so I add this to my posting. Thank you for the comment(s).

Answer (score 1):

For given numeric values of `ϵ` and `c` you can use `FindRoot`:

```
eq = x ϵ + (-ϵ) x^-ϵ - c (-ϵ) x^(-ϵ - 1) == 0;
FindRoot[eq /. {c -> 2, ϵ -> 3/4}, {x, 1}]
(* {x -> 1.38718} *)
```

For arbitrary analitycal values of `ϵ` and `c` the equation seems to be unsolvable. However, if you can threat `ϵ` as a small parameter (like in perturbation theory), I would suggest to find the solution as power series w.r.t. `ϵ`:

```
n = 2; (* number of terms in expansion *)
coeffs = Table[a[i], {i, 0, n - 1}];
rule = x -> coeffs.Table[ϵ^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + O[ϵ]^n
Reduce[Thread[List @@ Normal[eq /. rule][[1]] == 0], {a[0], a[1], a[2]}]
```

As the result we  have expressions for the first `n` series coeffients `a[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) can be used to find the perturbation expansions. First, simplify your equation:

```
eqn = x ϵ+(-ϵ) x^-ϵ-c (-ϵ) x^(-ϵ-1) == 0;
FullSimplify[eqn]
```

> x^(-1 - ϵ) (c - x + x^(2 + ϵ)) ϵ == 0

So, assuming $x\neq 0$ and $\epsilon \neq 0$, we have:

```
seqn = FullSimplify[eqn, x != 0 && ϵ != 0]
```

> c + x^(2 + ϵ) == x

The solution for `x` when `ϵ` is 0 can be found from:

```
roots = Values @ Solve[seqn /. ϵ -> 0, x]
```

> {{1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c])}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c])}}

Choosing the first root and using [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
AsymptoticSolve[seqn, {x, roots[[1]]}, {ϵ, 0, 1}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c]) + (1/(
>       2 Sqrt[1 - 
>         4 c]))ϵ (-Log[2] + Sqrt[1 - 4 c] Log[2] + 2 c Log[2] + 
>          Log[1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c]] - Sqrt[1 - 4 c] Log[1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c]] - 
>          2 c Log[1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c]])}}